# Create separate dropdown on each option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have basic 2 dropdowns.Based on first dropdown select value I want to show 2nd dropdown but it should be independent value based.
Eg-

```
<select id="loc_type">
  <option value="1">unit</option>
  <option value="2">property</option>
</select>

<select id="my_locations">
  <option value="38564">loc1</option>
  <option value="38565">loc2</option>
  <option value="39206">loc3</option>
  <option value="38805">loc4</option>
  <option value="38436">loc5</option>
</select>
```

Expected output - Say I selected the first option. Then it loads second dropdown with value "loc1" selected.Also, it loads next drop-down with value "loc2" selected.Separate dropdown for each value.

Comment: Edit your question to share more info about expected output and also share your try.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <select id="loc_type" onchange="getComboA(this)">
```

then add this javascript code

```
       <script>
          function getComboA(selectObject) {
          var value = selectObject.value;              
          var element = document.getElementById('my_locations');             
          element.selectedIndex  = value-1;
           }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the data-group value of parent select dropdown in child select dropdown and display options only with the same data-group values.

Here's the working snippet

```js
$("#loc_type").change(function() {
  //store reference to current select
  var me = $(this);

  //get selected group
  var group = me.find(":selected").val();

  //get the child select by it's ID
  var child = $("#my_locations");

  //hide all child options except the ones for the current group, and get first item
  var newValue = child.find('option').hide().not('[data-group!="' + group + '"]').show().eq(0).val();
  child.trigger("change");

  //set default value
  child.val(newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="loc_type">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">unit</option>
  <option value="2">property</option>
</select>

<select id="my_locations">
  <option data-group ="1" value="38564">loc1</option>
  <option data-group ="1" value="38565">loc2</option>
  <option data-group ="1" value="39206">loc3</option>
  <option data-group ="2" value="38805">loc4</option>
  <option data-group ="2" value="38436">loc5</option>
</select>
```

I recommend you to use radio buttons instead of dropdowns for separation (I think that drop-down with single option is of no use)

Here's the working snippet with separate radio buttons

```js
$("#loc_type").change(function() {

  if (this.value == 1) {

    $("#opt1").show();
    $("#opt2").hide();


  } else if (this.value == 2) {

    $("#opt2").show();
    $("#opt1").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#opt1 {
  display: none;
}

#opt2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="loc_type">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">unit</option>
  <option value="2">property</option>
</select>


<div id="opt1">
  <input type="radio" name="unit" value="38564">Loc1
  <input type="radio" name="unit" value="38565">Loc2
  <input type="radio" name="unit" value="39206">Loc3
</div>

<div id="opt2">
  <input type="radio" name="property" value="38805">Loc4
  <input type="radio" name="property" value="38808">Loc5
</div>
```

Comment: if I select unit it should populate 3 separate dropdowns. If I select 2 it should populate 2 separate dropdowns.

Comment: Separate dropdowns(drop down with only one option)? what kind of use it will have?

Comment: you can use Radio button instead

Comment: @Pranav I have updated my answer with radio buttons comment if you need anything else